# Would retrofitting weep holes reduce dampness?

Tags: exterior

Our house is two story brick veneer and currently has no weep holes on the bottom level. It does have a damp course and some moss under the damp course. I'm currently getting moisture and dampness and want to know whether weep holes or vents would make a difference.

Also, would a bricklayer be the best person to contact to do this work? The house is on a concrete slab on the ground.

Comment: How much airgap is there between the veneer and the structural wall sheathing?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty much, yes. I think someone with experience needs to see what you are dealing with (the "level" of the moisture). The damp course should be preventing moisture issues... my question would be why isn't it, or why do you have so much moisture, or is this actually a moisture issue? There might be some other issue, like rain leaking into the wall cavity.

Weep holes and/or vents could help (if they are necessary). A brick layer should have the experience to do this. It is not terribly complicated procedure; I would expect many construction workers would have the know-how to perform the "surgery". The one thing critical to having any contractor work on your house is that they are bonded and insured.

Comment: I am not sure weep holes are the right thing to do. I would want to seal the brick. My last house had 1 brick wall and the upstairs window leaked into the wall. there was no mold when we purchased the house but when remodeling the plywood and most of the studs were gone from rot. It was a big pain rebuilding that load bearing wall and adding tyvek to keep the water out. If water or moisture is running down the wall you will end up with problems in the long run (even with weep holes).

Comment: @EdBeal I think that someone should look at it... seems like whenever I pass blind judgement (to weep or not to weep) I'm wrong... I think that the same thing goes for sealing the brick; it's a fine idea (I have a couple more in my pocket), but it could also possibly conceal a problem by fixing a symptom. I would just leave the moss and let everything be until a contractor takes a look... to help the contractor see the issue (if there is one).

Comment: I do agree with having it checked so spike56au dosen't have the problem I had.

Comment: I agree, have a licensed and bonded mason (bricklayer) look at it. You can't just drill weepholes into the brick. If there is a void behind the brick veneer , then a moisture barrier needs to be installed and sealed to the bottom ledge. (Usually these weephole courses are located a few inches below the finished floor, for obvious reasons.)

Comment: If the upper courses have weepholes , I find it odd the bottom course doesn't also. Something else could be going on here, like the bottom section could be a structural section (with 8" thick brick) and not have a void, in which case sealing the brick might be all it needs. (Brick sealers last 5-10 years depending on weather conditions.) if the bottom section is structural, it could have cells that were not filled (grouted solid). That would allow water to penetrate the brick, fill up the empty cells and eventually "leak" out into the house.

Comment: Ed is right in that you don't want the moisture getting back there in the first place.  Weep holes are only there for if your sealant fails.